# Change text inside <h2> Text I would change </h2> element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the text inside

HTML element using javascript, but I have no idea about how to do it. ¿Any help?

I've got it defined like:

```
<h2 id="something">Text I want to change.</h2>
```

Im trying to do it with:

```
document.getElementById("something").value = "new text";
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You should use jQuery for that, it works everywhere.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use **[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)**:

```
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "new text";
```

Answer (score 12):

If the element only contains text, `textContent` works better and faster than `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("something").textContent = 'new text';
```

Good luck
:)

Answer (score 4):

Though the following code would be the **fastest** alternative to slow `.innerHTML`:

```
var element = document.getElementById('something');

// removing everything inside the node
while (element.firstChild) {
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
}

// appending new text node
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('new text'));
```

And here is the benchmark:

[image: JSPerf]

**JSPerf:** http://jsperf.com/replace-text-in-node

Comment: (just for info) You can also remove all child nodes with `element.textContent = '';` ... 
`textContent` on its own (as in my suggestion) performs well [**JSPref**](http://jsperf.com/replace-text-in-node/3)