# How do I change an element's text through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

I have tried textContent and innerHTML, I tried to get element by ID, class and tag but nothing is working. I am pretty sure I am missing something. How could I change the paragraphs inside the headings, and the headings themselves as well?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: firstly i tried const name = document.querySelector('#one') after giving first paragraph in H2 an id, and then name.textContent = "..", didn't work. So then I tried document.getElementById() and also didnt work

Comment: But you need to specify an ID for the paragraph. You don't have any elements with the ID `one`.

Comment: @whiteroses - [That works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/g58eyr61/1/).

Comment: that is not the code you have in your question

Comment: @User456 - They did say *"...after giving first paragraph in H2 an id..."* so I assumed it matched. :-) @​whiteroses - Perhaps you made the common mistake of putting `#` in the `id`? `id="#one"` instead of `id="one"`? You shouldn't have the `#` in the `id`. It would be much easier to help you if you actually **showed** us what you tried, rather than describing it. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Perfect, thank you! And yes, I sadly did the mistake of putting the # inside the ID, such a minor mistake that had me pulling my hair for the past 10 minutes. I even had '#' registered twice..

Comment: Sorry for not adding an accurate example, was too frustrated. Very sorry.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are many examples here doing what you're trying to do, even searching for super specific text like "*javascript change h2 text*" turns up [a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274274/change-text-inside-h2-text-i-would-change-h2-element-using-javascript). Of course there are also many ways to solve the problem and if that one doesn't suit try some more searches ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, paste your paragraph's id attribute inside the getElementById thing.

```
var paragraph = document.getElementById("id-of-your-paragraph");

paragraph.innerHTML = "Hello its a new text!";
```